# When is a string not a string when using JWT?

Tags: string, typescript, nestjs, typeof

I am working with JWT and have the following function:

```
export async function decodeJwt(token: string): Promise<string> {
  console.log('token is a string: ', typeof token === 'string');
  const payload = await jwt.verify(token, RSA_PUBLIC_KEY);
  console.log('payload: ', payload);
  return payload;
}
```

When this is called, however, the type of the `token` variable is not a string. In other words, the first line reports back that `token` is not a string.

How is that even possible?

The reason I am checking is that the call to `jwt.verify()` returns the error:

```
 jwt must be a string
```

This is strange because I call it with a string value for `token` here:

```
async function handleSessionCookie(token: string, req: Request) {
  try {
    const payload = await decodeJwt(token);
    console.log('payload: ', payload);
    req['userId'] = payload.sub;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('handleSessionCookie Error: Could not extract user from the request: ', err.message);
  }
}
```

It's strings all the way.

What is going on?

Comment: Hi, what is the typeof of token? and what happens if you convert it with String(token) in decodeJwt()?.

Comment: @OscarVelandia Thanks for chiming in.  I figured it out -- the first string in the call chain was pulled from a cookie and was coming in as an object.  I'll answer my own question to explain the issue.

Answer (score 0):

i believe that `token` is an empty string in

```
export async function decodeJwt(token: string): Promise<string> {
```

can you check?